HTTPS request on SIM A7672X usigng the tinyGSM Lib
I have been trying to make an HTTPs request with the SIM A7672X module using the tinyGSM lib but am having issues, i was following the example from: randomnerdtutorials with minor modifications as we use a different SIMCOM model, below is my code:
    #include <Arduino.h>

    #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_A7672X

    // #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM7000SSL
    #define TINY_GSM_RX_BUFFER 1024 // Set RX buffer to 1Kb

   // Set serial for debug console (to the Serial Monitor, default speed 115200)
#define SerialMon Serial
#define SerialAT Serial0

#include <TinyGsmClient.h>
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>

#define TINY_GSM_DEBUG SerialMon
const char apn[] = "internet.ng.airtel.com";
// const char apn[] = "web.gprs.mtnnigeria.net";
const char gprsUser[] = "";
const char gprsPass[] = "";

// Server details
const char server[] = "gist.githubusercontent.com";
const char resource[] = "/RuiSantosdotme/7db8537cef1c84277c268c76a58d07ff/raw/d3fe4cd6eff1ed43e6dbd1883ab7eba8414e2406/gistfile1.txt";
const int port = 443;
// const int port = 80;

TinyGsm modem(SerialAT);

TinyGsmClientSecure client(modem);
HttpClient http(client, server, port);

#define UART_BAUD 115200

#define PIN_TX RX
#define PIN_RX TX

void setup()
{
  // Set Serial Monitor baud rate
  SerialMon.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  SerialMon.println("Wait...");

  // Set GSM module baud rate and Pins
  SerialAT.begin(UART_BAUD, SERIAL_8N1, PIN_RX, PIN_TX);
  delay(6000);

  // Restart takes quite some time
  // To skip it, call init() instead of restart()
  SerialMon.println("Initializing modem...");
  // modem.restart();
  // modem.init();

  String modemInfo = modem.getModemInfo();
  SerialMon.print("Modem Info: ");
  SerialMon.println(modemInfo);

  Serial.println("Make sure your LTE antenna has been connected to the SIM interface on the board.");
  delay(5000);
}

void loop()
{
  modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass);

  SerialMon.print("Waiting for network...");
  if (!modem.waitForNetwork())
  {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");

  if (modem.isNetworkConnected())
  {
    SerialMon.println("Network connected");
  }

  SerialMon.print(F("Performing HTTPS GET request... "));
  http.connectionKeepAlive(); // Currently, this is needed for HTTPS
  int err = http.get(resource);
  if (err != 0)
  {
    SerialMon.println(F("failed to connect"));
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }

  int status = http.responseStatusCode();
  SerialMon.print(F("Response status code: "));
  SerialMon.println(status);
  if (!status)
  {
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }

  SerialMon.println(F("Response Headers:"));
  while (http.headerAvailable())
  {
    String headerName = http.readHeaderName();
    String headerValue = http.readHeaderValue();
    SerialMon.println("    " + headerName + " : " + headerValue);
  }

  int length = http.contentLength();
  if (length >= 0)
  {
    SerialMon.print(F("Content length is: "));
    SerialMon.println(length);
  }
  if (http.isResponseChunked())
  {
    SerialMon.println(F("The response is chunked"));
  }

  String body = http.responseBody();
  SerialMon.println(F("Response:"));
  SerialMon.println(body);

  SerialMon.print(F("Body length is: "));
  SerialMon.println(body.length());

  // Shutdown
  http.stop();
  SerialMon.println(F("Server disconnected"));

  modem.gprsDisconnect();
  SerialMon.println(F("GPRS disconnected"));

  // Do nothing forevermore
  while (true)
  {
    delay(1000);
  }
}

and bellow is the output from the serail monitor:
Initializing modem...
Modem Info: ATI  Manufacturer: INCORPORATED Model: A7672E-FASE Revision: 
    A7672M7_V1.11.1 IMEI: 867255079839140 +GCAP: +CGSM,+FCLASS,+DS
Make sure your LTE antenna has been connected to the SIM interface on the board.
Waiting for network... success
Network connected
Performing HTTPS GET request... failed to connect


There are two things you could do to rectify the error. 1) instead of print out "failed to connect", print err to see what it return? 2) Instead of creating a global client instance, move the line HttpClient http(client, server, port); into the loop().

@hcheung thanks so much i am going to try this and revert back soon

which sim card you are using ?
if airtel then apn will be airtelgprs.com

@hcheung moving the line HttpClient http(client, server, port); into the loop() did not work for me and printing the error gives -1

in my country its "internet.ng.airtel.com", i tried this "airtelgprs.com" though it still did not work
